# Sort list based on sum of two object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, ramda.js

I have list of these objects:

```
var alice = {
  name: 'Alice',
  a: 2,
  b: 8
};
var bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  a: 4,
  b: 5
};
var clara = {
  name: 'Clara',
  a: 1,
  b: 22
};
```

I want to sort them ascending or descending (passed as parameter) based on the sum of `a` and `b` properties i.e for the descending case the list has to be sorted with this ordering: clara (total: 23), alice (total: 10), bob (total: 9)

What's the best way to do it in javascript? Solution using `Ramda.js` is preferable/acceptable.

Thank you

Comment: why so many downvotes here?

Comment: Okay.. I answered before reading your comment. Hope my answer would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check solutions both in pure js and Ramda.js [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hj1kczzp/)

```js
var alice = {
  name: 'Alice',
  a: 2,
  b: 8
};
var bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  a: 4,
  b: 5
};
var clara = {
  name: 'Clara',
  a: 1,
  b: 22
};

var array = [alice, bob, clara];

// solution with pure js
var comparingFn = (obj1, obj2) => {
  var sum1 = obj1.a + obj1.b;
  var sum2 = obj2.a + obj2.b;
  return sum2 - sum1;
};

var array1 = array.sort(comparingFn);
console.log(array1);

// combining Ramda.js with comparing function above.
var array2 = R.sort(comparingFn, array);
console.log(array2);

// solution with Ramda.js
var sortFn = R.sortBy(R.compose(R.sum, R.props(['a', 'b'])));
var array3 = R.reverse(sortFn(array));
console.log(array3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was interested in last one, as I was trying to do it with `sortBy`